# deep clone method in generic class

Tags: java, clone, protected

we are implementing a linked list class using node objects (which we also created) in my class. We decided to override the clone method to show the difference between shallow and deep cloning. But I do not understand how we achieved being able to clone the items that the nodes store when the nodes are generic.

At first I didn't see the issue because while the clone method is protected under object since everything is a subclass of object it should be fine. I mean I know it shouldn't work if they don't implement the cloneable interface but I didn't understand why I was seeing a protected class error in IntelliJ. I did a bit more reading on protected methods and I now understand that while I can use protected methods within a subclass in a different package, the instance I use it on must still be the subclass, or subclasses of that subclass. So i can't even call the clone method on the object superclass itself within the subclass.

So i understand the issue, but I don't understand the solution given. It just says we tricked the compiler but we don't go deeper.

code below

```html
// Exercise 1:  Class must be redeclared to implement the Cloneable interface.

public class LinkedNode<I> implements Cloneable {
    protected I item;
    protected LinkedNode<I> nextNode;
    
    public LinkedNode(I x)
    {
        setItem(x);
    }
    
    // Getters/setters are automatically generated using eclipse.
    // Use: Source menu -> Generate Getters and Setters

    public I item() {
        return item;
    }
    
    public void setItem(I item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    
    public LinkedNode<I> nextNode() {
        return nextNode;
    }
    
    public void setNextNode(LinkedNode<I> nextNode) {
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    // Exercise 1: Add a public shallow clone() method.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public LinkedNode<I> clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        /* This was acceptable for exercise 1 - a shallow clone
        return super.clone();
        */

        // Exercise 2: A deep clone.  Copy each instance variable,
        // clone()-ing the ones that are references to other objects.
        LinkedNode<I> newNode = (LinkedNode<I>)super.clone();
        if(newNode.nextNode != null)
            newNode.nextNode = this.nextNode.clone();

        // Clone the item if we can.  Types that encapsulate primitive types like
        // Double, Integer, etc. are not cloneable because they are immutable.
        // But since they are immutable, this causes no problems for our list.
        try {
            //newNode.item = this.item.clone();   We can't do this because we can't require a generic type to be
            // cloneable, so there's no guarantee that a public clone method exists.  (You'd think we could
            // restrict I so that it implements cloneable, i.e. <I extends Cloneable>, but this does not work.)
            // Moreover, Integer, Double, etc. are not cloneable, so if the item is one of these types
            // we can't even shallow clone it.   But, such types are immutable, so
            // if we can't clone them, it is OK.   We use the following magical incantation to try to
            // call the possibly protected clone() method in a way that bypasses the compiler's objections.
            // If an exception arises, we do nothing and assume that the object was immutable and don't clone anything.
            newNode.item = (I) this.item.getClass().getMethod("clone").invoke(this.item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return newNode;
    }

}
```

Comment: The solution given used a feature of Java called reflection: in Java, you are able to change a program's code at runtime, see [Reflective programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming).
Basically: the compiler doesn't allow you to call the function, because it is protected. Because this is a problem for you, you sort of 'hack' the compiler to do what you want.
I would not encourage this kind of programming. There is usually a reason why a library would not expose a function or field and therefore you should not try to 'hack' into it to still get it.

Comment: Correction: `you sort of 'hack' the compiler to do what you want.` should be `you sort of 'hack' the program to do what you want.`

Comment: @blijde_broers Thanks, I don't fully understand how this still works since I haven't covered reflective programming but at least now I know where to look.

Comment: You're welcome! If you need any more help, you can comment here.

Comment: The `Cloneable` interface has many problems and using it doesn't guarantee you will actually get a deep copy. If a member of the object you want to copy doesn't implement `Cloneable` it creates a shallow copy. Usually if you know the type of the object you use a copy constructor/method or if you don't know the type use reflection/serialization&desiralization libraries. E.g. `SerializationUtils.clone(serializable)`.

Comment: @Erik Eidt I've undeleted it. I didn't think anyone was going to answer or that it would get downvoted and removed as most of my questions do. Sorry about that